# How to set up property variable from QML to CPP in Blackberry 10?

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I reference [pullmybeard](https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/blob/master/pullmybeard/assets/pullmybeard.qml) to work on drag and drop effect.

To do something programmatically, I would use cpp rather than QML itself.
But I face problem in setting property variables. Here is my code segments:

```
Container *playerContainer = Container::create();
           playerContainer->setLayout(new AbsoluteLayout);
           playerContainer->setLayoutProperties(AbsoluteLayoutProperties::create().x(posX).y(posY));`
```

I would set a variables to this `playerContainer` in order to store positionX and Y. Like [pullmybeard](https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/blob/master/pullmybeard/assets/pullmybeard.qml), inside ImageView id:beard, it sets property real dy. So, it can be used in onTouch hander.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a way to pass attributes from your C++ to your QML.
To do that, you can use **setContextProperty("propertyName", property)**
You can have a look there to see how to implement it : http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/dev/integrating_cpp_qml/